# Meson project: can I have part of the source located elsewhere?

Tags: c++, build, meson-build

In a Meson project, how can I compile files (i.e. not just headers) located in an directory which is not in my project tree?

E.g.:

```
MyProj/
   src/
      meson.build
ExternalCode/
   src/
      file1.h
      file1.cpp
```

`include_directories` is just for headers...

If I use ".." in the files path, I get this error:

> meson.build:10:0: ERROR:  Subdir contains ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build ExternalCode as a part of your project, then I recommend fetch somehow this directory inside your project, e.g. using symbolic link and place meson.build file alongside. So, your project layout will look as:

```
MyProj/
   meson.build
   src/
      meson.build
   external/
      ExternalCode -> link to ...
      meson.build
```

Then, make aware meson of all sub-directories in the project placing this in top level meson.build file:

```
subdir('src')
subdir('external')
```

Answer (score 1):

yes but the external file must be picked up in the following way:
e.g.

```
source =  files(file1.cpp)
```

put in meson.build inside

```
ExternalCode/src
```

folder